# blueimp jquery file uploader - done event on ie9 is not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm having an issue on ie9, the done event (when the file has been uploaded) is not been fired.

Ie response is like it was a file to be downloaded, but the response should be json and also I have specified the type as application/json.

Is Working fine in chrome, ff, ie10 and ie11. Only on ie9 the done event is not working correctly.

I looked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300804/jquery-file-upload-not-firing-done-callback-in-internet-explorer-ie9) and tried the solution without success.

Does anyone also have this issue ?
Thanks

Comment: Please post a code snippet so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sanpopo, you can check the error in the demo example page: blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload. I'm using virtual box with Ie9